# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Array to string

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I am getting an error (Cannot implicitly convert type System.Array to string) while trying to loop through an array. I have followed the code and the for loop is bring back the correct value.

```
public static string[] name = new string[] { "Chris" };
        public static void FindMergeFielsa(WordprocessingDocument WPDoc, Dictionary<string, Array> WordMergeFields)
    {
        foreach (var field in WPDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SimpleField>())
        {
            string[] instruction = field.Instruction.Value.Split(splitChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (instruction[0].ToLower().Equals("mergefield"))
            {
                string fieldname = instruction[1];

                foreach (var fieldtext in field.Descendants<Text>())
                {

                    if (fieldtext.InnerText =="«_skils»")
                    {
                        //TODO
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string value = name[i];

                            //ERORR HERE Keeps Changing Value of Name "Chris" to system.string[] when put .ToString()
                            value = WordMergeFields.ContainsKey(fieldname) ? WordMergeFields[fieldname] : null;

                            if (value != null)
                            {
                                fieldtext.Text = value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The exceptionis happening on

```
value = WordMergeFields.ContainsKey(fieldname) ? WordMergeFields[fieldname] : null;
```

I have tried to turn the WordMergeFields[fieldname] to string but when this happens it is displaying the name with the word template which this code is connected to it bring up System.String[] where the name "chris" should be. I was just wondering how I can resolve the issue of coverting type system.array to string. Thanks for any help which you can give

Comment: WordMergeFields.Add("Name", name); this is just a dictionary which has the index of string to find the merge fields on the template and array

Comment: you can edit the original post...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `WordMergeFields` is a `Dictionary<string, Array> WordMergeFields`.

`WordMergeFields[fieldname]` will return an array.

Didn't you mean to declare it as a dictionary with value type `string`?

```
Dictionary<string, string> WordMergeFields
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the method signature, `WordMergeFields` is of type `Dictionary<string, Array>`.  So this:

```
WordMergeFields[fieldname]
```

would be of type `Array`.  You're trying to set an `Array` to a `string`:

```
value = WordMergeFields[fieldname]
```

Hence the error.  Maybe you want the first element for `WordMergeFields`?  Maybe `WordMergeFields` should be a dictionary of strings instead of arrays?  It's hard to follow what this code is doing, so I can't be certain.

I'm guessing the latter, based on your comment where you demonstrate usage:

```
WordMergeFields.Add("Name", name);
```

Assuming by the context of the word `name` that the value is a `string`, then you probably meant for `WordMergeFields` to be:

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

Note that a `string` *can* be implicitly converted to an `Array` because it's an array of characters.  So your usage works in one direction (setting a string to an array) but not in the other (setting an array to a string), mainly by coincidence rather than your own design.

Change the type to `Dictionary<string, string>` and it should work, at least given what we see here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want explicitly convert Array into string you should code this.

```
value = WordMergeFields.ContainsKey(fieldname) ? WordMergeFields[fieldname] : null;
```

Replace with

```
if(WordMergeFields.ContainsKey(fieldname) )
   value =  WordMergeFields[fieldname].FirstOrDefault();
```